# How to prevent diagonal scrolling in mobile Chrome/Safari

Tags: ios, css, google-chrome, mobile-website, mobile-chrome

Is there a way in Chrome and Safari on iOS to restrict scrolling to one direction at a time?  In other words, if I start scrolling an element vertically, I want to turn off the user's ability to scroll horizontally until the vertical scrolling is complete.  And vice versa.

In iOS native code this is called [`directionalLockEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619390-directionallockenabled), and in Microsoft browsers it's [`-ms-scroll-rails`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-ms-scroll-rails).

Does something like this exist in CSS that Chrome for iOS (or Safari for iOS, because they use the same rendering engine under the hood) will recognize?

If not, is there a javascript solution available, ideally a React-compatible npm package?

Answer (score 1):

If you're after a pure CSS solution, unfortunately there is nothing in the spec for locking scroll to a single axis at a time.

There are some great points on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58190439/dont-allow-horizontal-scroll-when-scrolling-vertically-and-vice-versa), including some vanilla JS solutions if your use case requires locking the scroll behaviour to one axis at a time.