# Preventing trackpad scroll direction snap in particular div

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a webpage that normally snaps to predominant direction of scroll when it starts, the default behavior web browsers have: if the div is scrollable in both directions, the scroll direction is locked to the first axis that the user moved their fingers more, and unlocked if the user also moves their fingers in the other axis more than some threshold amount.

This works great and natural for almost everything though I have some canvas-like (for clarity: NOT HTML canvas, I'm talking about regular divs here) div that I want to disable this behavior as for navigating inside that particular view, it's counter-intuitive.

How can I disable axis locking for a particular element?

Comment: @onkarruikar what do you mean by snapping javascript? i don't have any js behavior. the snapping functionality, as I've said in the question, is Safari's default scrolling behavior while using a trackpad.

Comment: Do you mean the user can scroll both axes at the same time? And do you want to apply to a div or a canvas? Some code of what you are having is also good.

Comment: @Duannx user can already scroll both axes but when scroll first starts it tends to lock into the predominant axis (the one the fingers moved more initially). if I apply enough "pressure" to the other axis it frees. what I'm trying to remove is that initial locking and making both axes freely scrollable without one having predominance. and i'm applying to a div.

Comment: You should provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @FelipeSaldanha reproducible example of what? I'm talking about any div that is scrollable.

Comment: Are you sure about the behavior you described in your question? AFAIK there's no spec stating that a browser should lock the scroll axis on user interaction. Showing a small piece of code where this happens would help attract answers to your question.

Comment: @FelipeSaldanha I don't think it's spec, more like macOS's default behavior on any scrollable on trackpads. I'm sure about the behavior, I can replicate it consistently and it's the default behavior of Safari + trackpad scrolling anyway (though can't post anything as it's result of human interaction with trackpad and which direction fingers scroll).

Comment: If it's an issue related only to Safari/WebKit, check out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58329916).

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu I understand what you mean but I am too lazy to write down a complete answer. The idea is to add `overflow: hidden` to your div and scroll it by JS. Whenever the user holds the mouse and moves, you should add `transform: translate` to your div based on the movement of the cursor. Hope this can help

Comment: @Duannx yup, thought of it. I think it would "work" but I'm just not sure about performance

Comment: @FelipeSaldanha hmmm. checked it out now, seems like exact opposite of what I want to do (they want locking whereas I want unlocking) though that might give a clue about what I'd try (e.g. trying opposite of what they do, when applicable). thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Locking of scroll axis is not a part of any of the current the Web APIs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API so it is a property of the user agent (browser or browser+OS). This means that there is likely no solution, and if there is one it will probably only work for a specific browser.